# WPF Slanted TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, msdn, tabitem

I am modifying the `Header` of a `TabItem` to conditionally display an `Image`, which led me to this MSDN article: [HeaderedContentControl.Header Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.header%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I attempted the code and substituted in my conditional image, which does what I expect.

However, the image in that example shows the `TabItem`s with a different style than what I got when I ran my example. Where can I get the style for the slanted `TabItem`s in the MSDN example?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you also apply the style for the `HeaderedContentControl` from the example?

```
<Style TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
        <StackPanel>
          <Grid>
            <Rectangle Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
          </Grid>
          <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

This overrides the default `ControlTemplate` of the control. Also, if you use `TabControl` instead of `HeaderedContentControl`, it is possible that the results vary.

Comment: The second example on the page looks to be unrelated to the `TabItem` example.